# What is the idea behind "heat shrink tubing"?

Tags: soldering, wire, insulation

I have ordered some tubes that are labelled as "heat shrink tubing". I wanted them to cover non-insulated wires in the montage, to prevent them touching something unwanted by chance, or each other.

I only used the regular tubes so far. I have discovered that the "heat shrink tubing" really shrinks when heated but I do not understand how this could be helpful. What is the idea behind this tubing, and how is they ability to shrink useful? And how to heat them for shrinking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ability to shrink is usefull to fix it into place. For example if you solder 2 wires together you have a part where you remove the insulation to solder the wires. Heatshrink tubing can be placed over the solder joint and heated up. If the correct size tubing is chosen it will shrink enough that you can't move the tubing from the solder joint, thus "repairing" the insulation you removed.

Heating the heatshrink tubing is best done with hot air, but in a pinch a common lighter will work too. Make sure you heat up the entire heatshrink tubing, for optimal result.

Comment: And it is so effective when used to repair damaged wire coverings as well - I have just used it for a monitor cable where the outer cover had frayed and broken. Looks so much better now. Its uses are many - even just securing cable in place - often better than zip or cable ties...

Comment: My ghetto JTAG connector is flat cable soldered to male header pins, i used some tube on each wire/pin to mitigate the risk of shorts and provide some mechanical support for when i disconnect and connect the JTAG

Comment: Be aware... Not all heat shrink is created equal.  Be sure the electrical and mechanical specifications match your application (like working voltage, temperature (cold?), UV exposure, flame resistance, and any required agency approvals (like UL).

Comment: You can also hold a soldering iron underneath it so the hot air rises up - that is even dodgier than a lighter but good enough for hobby work if you don't have money for more tools.

Comment: When I worked in an electronics factory we had a commercial quality hair dryer for shrinking tubing.

Comment: Rubbing the side of a soldering iron tip up and down the tube works well most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I found it is possible to shrink it by holding the soldering iron few mm apart but not touching. Kind of high art but this can be done if you try it first and have no better tools yet. But it shrinks very unevenly this way so not the best approach.

Hair dryer did not work at all for me, same as nothing. It is probably not hot enough. 60 C is already hot enough to burn the human skin; likely the dryer is designed to deliver air not much above this temperature.

Comment: Some heat shrink can be done with a hair dryer, but others can't; it depends on what the shrink temperature is.

Comment: The motivation to post this answer was the abundance of talking I found this could be done. Same as nothing!

Comment: Wouldn't recommend it since if you accidentally touch the tip with the tube, you might have to get a new tip. Any form of melted plastic is bad news for solder tips... and no, there's no sensible way to clean them with chemicals beyond flux, most will do more harm than good. Just buy any cheap hot air gun in your average hardware store, doesn't need to be anything fancy.

Comment: The question is what heatshrink tubing is for, not how to shrink it. This post does not answer the question.

Comment: It says "And how to heat them for shrinking?"

Comment: @Lundin probably not so dramatically but probably it would be required to cool down the iron and file the tip. I agree not the best approach.

Comment: You are correct. I read it twice without reading the last line.